# Returning a whole MYSQL table data on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I found this code once...

```
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$rs_stuff = select($sql_select);

while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_stuff)) {

echo ($res("Name")."<br />");

}
```

It works well, it returns all names found in "Name" col, the problem is I want it to make to return all data in that table, like if I just typed "SELECT * FROM users" on mysql, I don't understand much of PHP, I tried to do this:

```
echo("<br />\n".$res);
```

But when trying to run this on the page, I just got a empty blank with "Array" written on it...
 Is it possible to do this without putting the col names in the php?

(Sorry about my English, it is not my main language.)

Comment: learn basic php first

Comment: `echo`does not print arrays... use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `$res` is a Array

use:

```
print_r($res);
```

or if you want a better view of it:

```
echo '<pre>';
  print_r($res);
echo '</pre>';
```

OR

you can use:

```
echo ($res["Name"]."<br />");
```

also, on this second option, watch out for multidimensional arrays. Your `$res` might be one. In which case it will be:

```
echo ($res[0]["Name"]."<br />");
```

if you have only one result. I suggest you go with the first choice and see how your `$res` looks like before echoing strings ;)

Either way, please find a good PHP tutorial as it is CLEAR that you lack basic knowledge of how to use and manipulate PHP code.

Hope it helps! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$rs_stuff = select($sql_select);
echo '<table>';//create the table
while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_stuff)) {

echo '<tr><td>'.$res['name'].'</td></tr>';

}
```

If you learning learn `mysqli_` or `PDO` their is no point in learning `mysql` as they are depriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "username";
   $password = "password";
   $dbname = "myDB";

   // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
           // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       print_r($row)
    }
   } else {
      echo "0 results";
}
 $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please put all your rows in an array and then print.

```
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$rs_stuff = select($sql_select);
$arr = array();
while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_stuff)) {
  $arr[] = $res["Name"];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '<pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
foreach($res as $key => $value) {
    print $res[$key] . ' => ' . $value;
}
```

hope that helps :)

Comment: Almost it, it didn't return the col name, but it returned like


"value => value"
how could I fix it to return "row_name => value"?

Comment: print "Column Name is : " . $key . "  Associated value is : " .  $res[$key];

Answer (score 0):

It hink this will help:

```
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM users";
$rs_stuff = mysql_query($sql_select);

while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_stuff)) {
    foreach($res as $key => $value) {
        echo $key.': '.$value."<br />\n";
    }
 echo "<br />\n";
}
```

Loop trough the array of values in the columns and echo out the cells value in the column. 
I think this will look like this:

```
Name: John<br />
Usernmae: johndoe<br />
Age: 36<br />
<br />
Name: Christian<br />
Username: admin<br />
Age: 46<br />
<br />
```

Don't use `echo` to print out an array. When you use echo PHP wants to convert an array to a string. If you only want to get the arrays values use `print_r`. Or use this function:

```
function convertArraytoString($array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $return .= $key.': '.$value."<br />\n";
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Than you can convert to the array via `echo convertArraytoString($res);`